# QTime add seconds to new object

Tags: c++, qt5.5, qtime

I am using QT5.51. Why is t1 invalid?:

```
QTime t1 = QTime().addSecs(122);
qDebug() << t1.isValid() << t1.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

I expected to get "00:02:02" , but I get false "".

Comment: I have to mention that I recently changed from qt4 to qt5. I looked at the "C++ API changes" and found "Adding days to a null QDate or seconds to a null QTime will no longer return a valid QDate/QTime." Maybe thats the reason. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A newly default-constructed `QTime` object starts in an invalid state.

> #### [QTime::QTime()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#QTime-1)
>
> Constructs a null time object. A null time can be a `QTime(0, 0, 0, 0)` (i.e., midnight) object, except that `isNull()` returns `true` and `isValid()` returns `false`.

Adding seconds to an invalid time leaves it as invalid - after all, it's an invalid time point, not midnight as you seem to expect. It's pretty much a NaN-type behavior.

> #### [QTime QTime::addSecs(int s) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#addSecs)
>
> ...
>
> Returns a null time if this time is invalid.

---

To create a `QTime` in a valid state you can either use the other constructor

> #### [QTime::QTime(int h, int m, int s = 0, int ms = 0)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#QTime-2)
>
> Constructs a time with hour h, minute m, seconds s and milliseconds ms.

so a midnight-initialized `QTime` would be `QTime(0, 0)`; OP code should thus be adjusted like this:

```
QTime t1 = QTime(0, 0).addSecs(122);
qDebug() << t1.isValid() << t1.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

You can also use several other [helper static methods](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#static-public-members), depending on how you need to initialize it.

Comment: So I changed to QTime t1(0, 0, 0, 0); t1.addSecs(122)... It gets "true" but it doesnt add anything, why? If I assign t1.addSecs(122) to a new invalid QTime object "t2" it works.

Comment: because `addSeconds` doesn't add to the current object, but returns a new one with the added seconds

Comment: This answer should include information on how to create a valid QTime object.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig IDK there are various ways, and all seem obvious once you read the linked documentation; there's a constructor taking hours minutes, seconds and milliseconds, there are static methods to parse strings, taking the current time and many others... it's all in the doc.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it:

```
QTime t1(0,0,0,0);
t1 = t1.addSecs(122);
qDebug() << t1.isValid() << t1.toString("hh:mm:ss");

= true "00:02:02"
```